# subscribe method not working for observable?

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to create a mock service as follows.
my service is like

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Config } from '../../shared/config/env.config';
import { HttpBaseService } from '../../shared/http-base/http-base.service';
import { ResponseModel } from '../../shared/models/index';
import { InventoryIntake } from './inventoryintake';

@Injectable()
export class InventoryIntakeService {
    list:InventoryIntake[];
    constructor(private http: HttpBaseService) { }

    get(): Observable<ResponseModel<InventoryIntake[]>> {
        this.list=[{
            supplier_name:"atami",
            metric_reference:"55665589",
            date_received:new Date("10-5-2017"),
            date_transferred:new Date("15-5-2017")
        },
        {
            supplier_name:"green bits",
            metric_reference:"4555589",
            date_received:new Date("10-5-2017"),
            date_transferred:new Date("15-5-2017")
        }]
        let response = new ResponseModel<InventoryIntake[]>();
        response.data = this.list;
        console.log("called")
        return Observable.create(response);
    }
}
```

and from component I am calling like

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpBaseService } from '../../shared/http-base/http-base.service';
import {InventoryIntakeService} from './inventoryintake.service';
import {InventoryIntake} from './inventoryintake'
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'inventory-report',
    templateUrl: './inventoryintake.component.html',
    providers: [ HttpBaseService,InventoryIntakeService]
})

export class InventoryIntakeComponent implements OnInit {
   inventoryintake_list: InventoryIntake[] = [];
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,private InventoryIntakeService:InventoryIntakeService) {
    }

    getIntakeList(): void {
        this.InventoryIntakeService.get()
          .subscribe((inventoryintake_list) => {
            this.inventoryintake_list = inventoryintake_list.data;
            console.log(this.inventoryintake_list);
        })
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
       this.getIntakeList();
    }
}
}
```

when I do this. iam getting error saying that .subscribe is not a function.
How can I fix this?

How can I create a mock service with return type observable?
is the problem is with create method of observable?

Comment: The code `this.InventoryIntakeService.get()` should not even compile. Please show us more of the component's code, including the constructor.

Comment: code updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to import observable from

```
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/rx';
```

instead of

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

and then I have to use

```
 observable.of(response)
```

this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Don't call the method `get()` directly on the `InventoryIntakeService` class. Create an instance of your service in the constructor.

```
constructor(private inventoryIntakeService: InventoryIntakeService) {}

getIntakeList(): void {
    this.inventoryIntakeService.get()
        .subscribe(inventoryintake_list => {
            this.inventoryintake_list = inventoryintake_list.data;
            console.log(this.inventoryintake_list);
        },
    );
}
```

Comment: I have it in the constructor. lik constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,private InventoryIntakeService:InventoryIntakeService) {
    }

Comment: its not he answer

Comment: Don't name the instance identically to the class !!! change it to `constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,private inventoryIntakeService:InventoryIntakeService) { }` and let me know if the error persists. @vishnuprasadkv

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.create` expects, as an argument, a function that is invoked when an observer subscribes to the observable. Try using `Observable.of` instead, passing it your `response`.